# PHP: Trying to send an email form with variables and an IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax

I am trying to make an email change depending on what variables are available.

There are a total of 6 operation id's, however 20 (the one shown below in the code) requires the machine code unlike the other operations.

```
$email = 
if ($OperationID == 20)
    {
        'Machine: '.$machCode."\r\n".
    }
"JobID: ".$jobid."\r\n" . 
"PartID: ".$part_id."\r\n" .
"\nNote: ".$message."\r\n";
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email);
```

If the '`if` statement' is not there an email can be sent that looks like the following

```
Machine:
JobID: 123456789
PartID: 123456789
Note: Test
```

I do not want this as there is a blank space next to 'machine'. I want the machine line to be removed unless, obviously, the `OperationID` is 20. So the email looks like the following:

```
JobID: 123456789
PartID: 123456789
Note: Test
```

How would I make it so the machine line is only activated when the Operation is equal to 20?

I currently get this error

> `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /var/www/ps_t/send_form_email.php on line 21 Call Stack: 0.0004 656768 1. {main}() /var/www/ps_t/punch.php:0` with the code used above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
$email = "";
if ($OperationID == 20)
{
     $email .= 'Machine: '.$machCode."\r\n";
}
$email .= "JobID : ".$jobid."\r\n" . 
          "PartID: ".$part_id."\r\n" .
          "\nNote: ".$message."\r\n";
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something this:

```
$email = '';
if ($OperationID == 20)
{
        $email .= 'Machine: '.$machCode."\r\n";
}
$email .= "JobID: ".$jobid."\r\n" . 
          "PartID: ".$part_id."\r\n" .
          "\nNote: ".$message."\r\n";
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($OperationID == 20)
{  
    $email = "Machine: ".$machCode."\r\n".
             "JobID: ".$jobid."\r\n" . 
             "PartID: ".$part_id."\r\n" .
             "\nNote: ".$message."\r\n";
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email);
}
else
{
    $email = "JobID: ".$jobid."\r\n" . 
             "PartID: ".$part_id."\r\n" .
             "\nNote: ".$message."\r\n";
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email);
}
```